# The warning when "git fetch"

Tags: git

Today, when I executed `git fetch`, i got the following warning.

I want to know why so.

```
Administrator@lizs MINGW64 /d/UPUPW_P7/htdocs/*** (lizs)
$ git fetch
libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
```

[image: libpng warning]

Comment: Your .png files are broken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a warning caused by libpng.

Upgrade libpng to the newest version.  Some of the warnings about "sRGB profile has been edited" that were generated by libpng-1.6.0 through 1.6.11 have been eliminated.

http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html